# High Bay LED light rebuild

Tags: led-driver, led-matrix

I've got a 200 W High Bay LED light from a friend. Its circuitry is blown up; it was connected to 380 V instead of 220 V, but it also had flickering issues before that.

I would like to build it a simple driver, because its circuitry is in some type of epoxy, it seems that it was built to be repair-resistant.

The LEDs are wired strangely; it has 300 LEDs in 30 groups of 10 LEDs. Each group has the 10 LEDs in parallel, and these 30 groups are connected in series. There are no resistors anywhere on the board, and I see no voltage indicators, only this:

[image: Specs]

Here is the circuit diagram of the LEDs. I'm not sure if that is sane, but maybe I'm too paranoid thinking they don't want the thing to last long.

[image: Led connection diagram]

Birds-eye view of the LEDs:

[image]

Testing with 1 to 3 V doesn't turn them on. I hooked up a MOSFET, a variable resistor, and a 13 V, 6 A power supply and tried higher voltages. I used two 27 Ω resistors (57 Ω) to connect to the LEDs. The metal wires in the picture are the resistors' legs; when measuring the voltage on the LEDs, they barely turn on at 4.9 ~ 5 V.

[image]

At 6.4 V all turn on dimly.

[image]

I tested up to 7.7 V but it does not shine as brightly as before. I didn't want to go any higher without asking first: could these be 9 V or 12 V? How do I find out?

If the LEDs are 5 V they sum up to 150 V; if they are 7.7 V they sum up to 231 V. I'm not sure if it's OK to run LEFs that way; if the LEDs are 9 V it means the driver was outputing 270 V and if they are 12 V the driver was putting out 360 V. The two polarised electrolytic capacitors in paralel with the output are 400 V, 22 μf capacitors.

I would like suggestions on what to do with it.

A- if the LEDs are 9 V or 12 V, can I hook them up with some simple protection circuit to to 240 V or 380 V, depending on the LEDs' voltage? Is that even save?

B - should I break the circuit up and put 300 LEDs in parallel at 9 V or 12 V with resistors? That's going to require an expensive power supply, I suppose.

Below some info on the 150 W LED. The one I got here is the 200 W version, same manufacturer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are chips that are designed to do such constant current driving straight from the mains. Otherwise, you could start by just using rectified and capacitor-filtered mains voltage directly. Use a variable auto transformer to bring the voltage up slowly. To improve filtering, you could add a so-called capacitance multiplier pass element, to provide additional voltage smoothing.

Comment: Any white LED will require about 3 to 3.2V.  However, it's possible that each "chip" contains 2 or more LEDs, wired in series.  That could give 6 to 6.4V, or 9 to 9.6V or whatever.  If you run one chip at a low enough current, you may be able to see.

Comment: thanks for your answers, how can i know the overall current and voltage? the first picture i posted say Hi-pot AC1.5kv 3.5MA, can i use those values to calculate voltage and current,? is that 3.5ma? is that miliamper? is int it written "mA" instead?

can i hook the think up to a incandecent lamp dimmer? 
like this one, https://www.electronics-lab.com/project/triac-based-lamp-dimmer/ and adding a full bridge rectifier + capacitor infront of the led circuit?

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica, can you recommend any chip i can try to drive from the main? will RM9003 Work? or do you know witch to try instead?